# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't recognize Windows Azure Tools 2.2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I recently installed [windows Azure SDK 2.2](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=net). But when I try to upgrade my project to point to windows azure 2.2 (previously 2.0) thru "properties" menu, VS didn't recognize it. There should be option to upgrade to the latest azure tools version installed in there, but there wasn't. I'm also try to update it manually by editing the project file (*.ccproj), but when reload it, the pop up for downloading azure tools 2.2 appears. It seems Visual Studio didn't recognize the windows azure tools 2.2. :(

Another problem is, I couldn't close my Visual Studio 2012. It shows this message:

> Unable to retrieve the Visual Studio service:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Credentials.IAzureCredentialsManager

I believe this is related to the Windows Azure SDK 2.2 I'd installed.

At the moment I'm still struggling to resolve this problem. :(

Please if anyone have any solution for this problem. Thanks.

Note:

- I'm using visual studio 2012 Premium (no update)
- I'd previously installed Windows Azure SDK 1.6-2.0
- I installed azure sdk 2.2 without uninstalling the previous versions.
- I'm using X64 based system

**UPDATE:**

Thanks guys for the answers. But unfortunately I have tried all of them, from reinstalling emulator until reinstall Visual Studio, but no luck.

If you have the same problem as me and couldn't resolve it, use the last resort: **Re-Install your OS**. It seems that the source of the failure came from deeper part. In my case, my company gave me new PC (which has new installment of OS) and there's no problem in the first time I install the azure.

Answer (score 4):

@Sebastián I just had the same thing happen moments ago though I am using VS2013 - I could not run the installer again either because it indicated it was already installed. Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

- Close VS
- Open Programs and Features from the control panel
- Locate "Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio  - v2.2"
- Highlight this item and click Change from the toolbar above
- Choose repair and let it re-install.
- No restart required, simply open VS and you should be good to go

Good luck!
j

Comment: I had this after install vs2013 side by side with 2012. neither version would open azure project anymore.  The above instructions fixed.

Comment: This worked for me. I had an issue with Visual Studio 2013 Community not  recognizing tools version 2.3. The above instructions fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Windows Azure SDK 2.2 via the Web PI download available at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/, I found that:

- Windows Azure Compute Emulator 2.2 and related tools were installed and available from the start menu (as expected)
- My existing Azure Cloud Services project properties showed Windows Azure Tools version: 2.1, and no option to upgrade to 2.2 (not expected)
- Creating a new Azure Cloud Services project only showed options for SDK versions I had previously installed (also not expected)

It appears that the Web PI installer skipped the Visual Studio components.

After running the same installer again, the Visual Studio components were installed and I could upgrade my project.

Try running the [Azure .NET SDK VS 2012 download](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) a second time.

Comment: It's happening the same to me. I have that error message when I close VS.  When I try to run the installation agin as you suggest, I don't have the option to install because it's already installed. I have uninstalled SDK 2.2 only to break my Visual Studio 2012 so I repaired it. But I'm stuck again in the same situation. Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael  doesn't work for me.  When I run the setup again, Web Installer grays out the Install button.  Tried uninstalling and installing the SDK 10 times, no help.  I am not sure what I am going to do after spending so much time installing VS2013 etc.